# Adding up values based on similar column word

Tags: subset, percentage

[image]
I am trying to combine the "n" column to matching word (there are multiple words from a big dataset).  That way the percentages reflect all of the combined "n" by circumstances of rescue, but they are subsetted by the different circumstances of rescue.

I subsetted the data so that only these two columns showed up by using:

```
subset.raptors.all.circumstances<-select(raptorswildone_noduplicates_allcircumstancesbystate, 'Circumstances of Rescue','n')
```

from the original data set (which had unncessary columns in it).  Now I just need to combine the alike circumstances of rescues.